# ¿Como activar el BroadcastReceiver despues de reiniciar?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

les explico mi problema, he creado una aplicación que tiene que lanzar una notificación cada día a una hora concreta. Para ello he desarrollado el siguiente código:

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(this, Alertas.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
cal.set (Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.valueOf(hora[0]));
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.valueOf(hora[1]));
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);
```

Donde Alertas es un BroadcastReceiver donde se ejecuta el siguiente código resumido:

```
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(farmacia.getNombre())
                        .setContentText(farmacia.getDireccion())
                        .setLights(Color.CYAN, 1000, 500)
                        .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 500, 2000, 500, 1000});

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, Inicio.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(Inicio.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

Cuando hago pruebas en el emulador, cambiando la fecha manualmente funciona correctamente, en el dispositivo físico también, pero cuando reinicio el dispositivo dichas alertas dejas de notificarse a la hora indicada, directamente no se muestra, solo lo hace la primera vez cuando activo las alertas, espero puedan ayudarme, es para mi proyecto final, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que el `BroadcastReceiver` lo tienes que registrar, regularmente se realiza en el método `onResume()`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

  // Registra el broadcast receiver para recibir mensajes.
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("mi-evento"));
}
```

y muy importante des registrarlo, lo puedes hacer en el método `onPause()`:

```
    @Override    
    protected void onPause() {
      // Desregistrar cuando la actividad no es visible!.
      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
      super.onPause();
    }
```

Comment: En primer lugar gracias por contestar @Elenasys, perdona mi ignorancia pero lo que me planteas; ¿Iniciaría el BroadcastReceiver y lo pararía cada vez que la aplicación estuviera activa o no? La funcionalidad que quiero implementar es que el BroadcastReceiver se active cuando pulso un switch y se quede activado hasta que dicho switch cambie a desactivado, que dicha funcionalidad ya la hace, el problema viene cuando reinicio el móvil, que deja de lanzar las notificaciones que se muestran en el código que he adjuntado.

Answer (score 1):

Añade la siguiente linean en el `<manifest>`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: En primer lugar gracias por contestar @aldakur, pero dicha respuesta no soluciona el problema.

Comment: Gracias por contestar @aldakur pero añado ese permiso en el manifest y cuando reinicio siguen sin activarse las alarmas. Espero puedas ayudarme, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hace tiempo me vi con un problema similar al tuyo. Te explico como lo solucioné yo.

Primero, separa tu BroadCastReceiver en una clase a parte.

```
public class MusicBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static MainActivity mainVar = null; // Esta será la referencia a la clase del MainActivity

    public MusicBroadcastReceiver() {}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    }

    public static void setMainActivityHandler(MainActivity main){
        mainVar = main;
    }

}
```

Después instanciala en el Main de tu aplicación. En mi caso, mi objeto se llamaba MusicBroadcastReceiver.

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new MusicBroadcastReceiver();
        MusicBroadcastReceiver.setMainActivityHandler(this);    // Le pasamos este activity para vincularlos
        IntentFilter callInterceptorIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.ANY_ACTION");
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, callInterceptorIntentFilter);
```

Segundo, declara el BroadcastReceiver en tu manifest.

```
<receiver
    android:name=".MusicReceiver.MusicBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.music.metachanged" />
        <action android:name="com.htc.music.metachanged" />
        <action android:name="fm.last.android.metachanged" />
        <action android:name="com.sec.android.app.music.metachanged" />
        <action android:name="com.nullsoft.winamp.metachanged" />
        <action android:name="com.amazon.mp3.metachanged" />
        <action android:name="com.miui.player.metachanged" />
        <action android:name="com.rhapsody.metachanged" />
        <action android:name="com.real.IMP.metachanged" />
        <action android:name="com.maxmpz.audioplayer.metachanged" />
        <action android:name="com.sonyericsson.music.metachanged" />
        <action android:name="com.rdio.android.metachanged" />
        <action android:name="com.samsung.sec.android.MusicPlayer.metachanged" />
        <action android:name="com.andrew.apollo.metachanged" />
        <action android:name="com.spotify.mobile.android.metadatachanged" />
        <action android:name="com.spotify.music.metadatachanged" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Tienes un ejemplo en mi repositorio:

https://github.com/helicida/FeatherLyrics_APP

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Hola @Sergi Barjola cual es el metodo de  registerReceiver(..); y que valor se pasa al intenet Filter,el package o cual ?